# How implement keras embedding layer with XLNet?

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I'm new to the python language and NPL implementation.
I'm trying to implement a sequential model with keras using a layer embedding.
I want to use a pre-trained XLNet model in this layer, but I haven't figured out how that works.

I find an implementation, but I don't know how to implement XLNet [github](https://github.com/zihangdai/xlnet/blob/master/README.md)

```
embedding = Embedding(MAX_LEN, 768, input_length = 100, name='embedding', trainable=True)
embedding.build(input_shape=(1,)) # the input_shape here has no effect in the build function
embedding.set_weights([embedding_mat])
model.add(embedding)
```

this example, the author use the file .csv from BERT for set_weights, but not find in documentation from XLNet

Can you help me?

thank you.

I am view documentation, but not find how implement in embedding layer from Keras.